# How to fix error in my strcat function

Tags: c++

The code below is in my header file:

```
char mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2) //strcat function
{
  mystrcpy(s1 + mystrlen(s1), s2);
  return s1;
}
```

The error is the return s1; "return value type does not match the function type." 
I know that the strcat function appends a copy of the source string to the destination string, but how would I fix this error. 
The other part of my code is in the main.cpp If you need more code just tell me.

Comment: I would put the main.cpp file there too because theres some errors there that pertain to the strcat fucntion, but its kinda of a long code

Comment: as paulsm4 correctly points out there's also the question of wether `mystrcat` should take care that `s1` actually has enough space to append `s2` onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature should look like

```
char* mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2)
 // ^~~~~~ Note the pointer
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you. I've been trying to figure this error out for like an hour

Comment: @user2548316: Be sure to upvote this answer, and mark it "accepted".  And please consider the other potential issues I mentioned in my post below.  IMHO ... PSM

Answer (score 1):

You function should return `char`, but you are returning `s1` that is `char*`

Make sure you understand problem that it's possible that there's no allocated space at the end of `s1`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the other way around. The return type should be `char *`.

Comment: with return char; an error comes up "type name is not allowed"

Comment: @user2548316, Well, you can't return a type, you have to return an expression of the return type.

Comment: @chris, I'm not sure that anything should be returned

Comment: @RiaD, The stdlib one returns a pointer to the end of the new string to allow for faster multiple calls rather than iterate the string again and again.

Answer (score 0):

1) ERROR:  "return value type does not match the function type
   CAUSE: s1 is char*; your signature returns "char"
   SOLUTION: change your signature to `char *`

2) What is mystrcpy()?  What errors might be lurking there?

3) More importantly, who allocates space for the "s1" you're returning?

4) What happens if the returned value is larger than the original value (a likely case)?  Do you get a buffer overrun?

5) What happens if the original value is read-only (another likely case)?

Etc...

Comment: By convention, if `s1` was read-only, it would be `const`, and couldn't have been passed as an argument (unless it is casted manually)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I would up vote your answer but my rep to too low